# Get the Full Process path from the prefetch file (offset address).

Tags: windows, prefetch, hexdump

I am in an attempt of listing  some details from the Windows Prefetch file such Filename, FileCreatedTime, 
FileModifiedTime,File Size, Process Name, Process Path,Run Counter & Last Run time.
Though there are many tools like Nirsoft WinPrefetchViewer and couple of more available. I thought of creating
one internally for my organization.
And coming to the point out of these many details I have cracked or extracted them except the Process full path
(For Eg. C:\Program Files (x86)\Mozilla Firefox\Firefox.exe in case Firefox executable). 
To give more details I have converted the .pf file into a hexdecimal format for extarcting the offset addresses
of the field and converted them to decimal or Asci accordingly. 
And spending considerable amount of time in exploring I was not able to find the offset address of the Full process 
path in the prefetch file.
It will be great if someone through light in this regard.

Comment: *"I have converted the .pf file into a hexdecimal format"* - That doesn't make much sense. The numeral system you use is concerned with **displaying** data only. It's just a different representation of the same data. There is no conversion. Unless you meant to write, that you converted the binary data to a string representation, using a base 16 numeral system.

Comment: There are couple of reason behind the creation of hexdump for the .pf file. 
First one being from most of the online resources such as Yogesh Kahtri and some others I could see them demonstrating what I was looking for by getting the hex values and later extrating the File Creation time,Modified, File size, Run counter & last run time by converting hex values to ACSII accordingly.
Second one being when I was doing this manually I was using hex editor to get the hex values along with the offset addresses
of the .pf file.

Comment: So these things made me thing in this way. And I was able to get all the values or data which I was intended to except the full process path. And after quite some amount of exploration I was not successful for this value.
Please suggest me if some other approaches are available.